# What will be the SQL query for ordering dates with respect to day name starting with tuesday?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

It should order it by week day names i.e., tuesdays come first, wednesdays next, and so on.

Here's what I have done:

```
SELECT hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date,'Day')
FROM employee
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'Day');
```

but it doesn't start ordering from tuesday...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean "starting with Tuesday"?

Comment: have to order it by week day names.. so tuesdays come first, wednesdays next, vice versa.

Comment: If you order by week day **names**, why does Tuesday come first? Friday is first, then Monday,  then Saturday, etc.  You probably mean something else, but it's not clear what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution that works internationally then do not use `TO_CHAR` as the day number is dependent on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting which will be different for different users/databases around the world. For much of Europe, Monday will be the first day of the week; for much of the Americas and Africa, Sunday is the first day of the week; for the Middle East, Saturday is the first day of the week; and, in Bangladesh, Friday is the first day of the week. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f889c12ae18a4e42509a4f33120ce96)

If you want a method independent of any NLS settings then use ISO weeks:

This will order it so that Monday is first, Tuesday second, ...

```sql
SELECT hire_date,
       TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
FROM   employee
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(hire_date) - TRUNC( hire_date, 'IW' ),
       hire_date
```

To get Tuesday first, then you can subtract a day:

```sql
SELECT hire_date,
       TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
FROM   employee
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(hire_date - 1) - TRUNC(hire_date - 1, 'IW' ),
       hire_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can keep the weekdays together and order them by including the weekday number:

```
SELECT hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
FROM employee
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'D'), hire_date
```

Unfortunately, this will start on Sunday or Monday, in most cases.  You can adjust for your particular setting by subtracting one or two days:

```
SELECT hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
FROM employee
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(hire_date - interval '1' day, 'D'), hire_date
```

Or you can be explicit:

```
SELECT hire_date, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
FROM employee
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(hire_date - interval '1' day, 'D', 'NLS_TERRITORY = 'AMERICA'), hire_date
```

Comment: could u explain me the interval keyword you have used?

Comment: `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` has no effect on the query. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f889c12ae18a4e42509a4f33120ce96) It is based on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting which you cannot pass as a parameter to `TO_CHAR` so this will fail to be a consistent solution in an international setting.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, you cannot pass `NLS_TERRITORY` to `TO_CHAR` so your edit to the "you can be explicit" query will fail with `ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2c7bd5d3eeec487e823bb9d53505d2d4).